# Get total of JSON values

Tags: javascript, json, jq

I return the following JSON to populate a highchart http://www.highcharts.com/

```
[["Graz", 5.0],["Rio de Janeiro", 3.0],["Bräcke", 2.0],["Campinas", 2.0],["Colchester", 2.0],["Cunewalde", 2.0],["Lille", 2.0],["London", 2.0],["Charleroi", 1.0],["Caracas", 1.0],["Butte", 1.0],["Buenos Aires", 1.0]]
```

rather than requery the database again. How would I get the total of the values returned? ie in this case 24.
I am still getting used to JSON, so would appreciate any help anyone can give...thanks

Comment: I wonder if it's possible with [tag:jq]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop through the results and add it up...

```
var data = JSON.parse('[["Graz", 5.0],["Rio de Janeiro", 3.0],["Bräcke", 2.0],["Campinas", 2.0],["Colchester", 2.0],["Cunewalde", 2.0],["Lille", 2.0],["London", 2.0],["Charleroi", 1.0],["Caracas", 1.0],["Butte", 1.0],["Buenos Aires", 1.0]]');

var total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  total += data[i][1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks...thats just what I had...except I was missing  the [1] on  data[i][1];

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete Jake's excellent answer, I would like to point out that, since the question is tagged with the `jquery` tag, another approach could be the use of `$.each`:

### Demo:

```js
function sumJSON(str) {
  var data = JSON.parse(str),
    total = 0;
  $.each(data, function(index, value) {
    total += value[1];
  });
  return total;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var string = '[["Graz", 5.0],["Rio de Janeiro", 3.0],["Bräcke", 2.0],["Campinas", 2.0],["Colchester", 2.0],["Cunewalde", 2.0],["Lille", 2.0],["London", 2.0],["Charleroi", 1.0],["Caracas", 1.0],["Butte", 1.0],["Buenos Aires", 1.0]]';
  $(".count").text( sumJSON(string) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Total: <span class="count"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is hardly a sexy answer, but it works.  Note, since it uses .length, it will only work on an array:

```
var
  jsonArr = [["Graz", 5.0],["Rio de Janeiro", 3.0],["Bräcke",2.0],["Campinas", 2.0],
    ["Colchester", 2.0],["Cunewalde", 2.0],["Lille", 2.0],["London", 2.0],
    ["Charleroi", 1.0],["Caracas", 1.0],["Butte", 1.0],["Buenos Aires", 1.0]],   
  total = 0;

for (var i in jsonArr) {
  total += jsonArr[i].length; 
}
console.log(total); // 24
```

Comment: Well, the data that the OP needs to handle is an array, so I don't really see your point here. I do like the fact that your approach would also work for objects, but that doesn't seem necessary in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely does not work on objects.  .length is an Array property. ...and when I began my post, there were no other answers -- the only point to my post.

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks that you already got a response, I would suggest a general solution for all possible formats, not only this one that has one-level array nesting, and doesn't even consider objects or whatever. The following code will recursively iterate objects and arrays looking for values:

```
function isArray(obj) {
  return !!(obj.length) && ((obj + "") !== obj);
}

function isObject(obj) {
  return obj.toString() === "[object Object]";
}

function getKeys(obj) {
  var keys;
  if (isArray(obj)) {
    keys = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      keys.push(i);
    }
  } else {
    keys = Object.keys(obj)
  }
  return keys;
}

function deepLength(arr) {
  var totalValues = 0;
  var keys = getKeys(arr);

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    if (isArray(arr[keys[i]]) || isObject(arr[keys[i]])) {
      totalValues += deepLength(arr[keys[i]])
    } else {
      totalValues++;
    }
  }
  return totalValues;
}
```

I just didn't invest too much time with the isArray and isObject functions and I would recommend you using maybe those from lodash or underscore, or whatever but definitely not these.

Answer (score 0):

since the question has got a `jq` tag, here it goes...:

```
echo "[[\"Graz\",5],[\"Rio de Janeiro\",3],[\"Bräcke\",2],[\"Campinas\",2],[\"Colchester\",2],[\"Cunewalde\",2],[\"Lille\",2],[\"London\",2],[\"Charleroi\",1],[\"Caracas\",1],[\"Butte\",1],[\"Buenos Aires\",1]]" | jq '[.[][1]] | add'
```